# python socket script to get data

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

I am running following netcat command to get data from remote server.

```
cat <(echo status) - | nc 10.10.10.10 25001
```

Now i am trying to write simple python script to do that but somehow it's hanging.

```
import sys
import socket
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn.connect(('10.10.10.10', 25001))
cmd = "status"
conn.send(cmd)
print conn.recv(1024)
conn.close()
```

Is there any good way to perform above task?

Comment: `echo "status" | nc -l -p 25001` and try `python <thescript>.py` in some other terminal and see

Comment: `Ncat: bind to 10.10.10.10:25001: Address already in use. QUITTING.` why you want to do that test?

Comment: Yeah, try some other port for now, since it is already in use :). I am not exactly sure what you want to start with :)

Comment: The data to send needs to be ib bytes e.g. data = b“hello“; check at which point your prog hangs by adding some extra print statements;

Comment: now i can see its sending `status` command to `nc -l -p 25000` port so my script sending `status` command correctly but not getting data in return. I have tried `conn.send(b'status')` option too but no luck still script just hanging

Comment: after further test with `echo "status" | nc -l -p 25001` test i can see return data so look like script is working but not working with server port..

Comment: In `tcpdump` i can see server received `status` command but didn't return any data, does python do return carriage character?

Comment: `conn.send(b'status\n')`  it works :) just added `\n`